# cURL command equivalent in powershell

Tags: curl, powershell-2.0

So I made a Confluence macro which executes a curl command in cmd.exe and gives me back a JSONObject as a string. The problem is, that he machine where our Confluence is doesn't recognize the curl command and the admins don't want to install the necessary files to make it work, so they told me to try and use a Powershell command.

The curl command is this: **`curl -u {user}:{pass} {url}`**. I need an equivalent for this in powershell 2.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using v2, you'll want to use [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) (v3 has [`invoke-webrequest`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849901.aspx) which makes this much simpler).

```
$webclient = new-object system.net.webclient;
$User = "user";
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString –String "P@sSwOrd" –AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $User, $PWord;
$webclient.Credentials = $Credential;
$webclient.DownloadString('url');
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen the v3 command which was 1000x easier to understand and use, but... Thanks for the v2 variant though :)